# Any hints on programming Dia with Python extensions?

Tags: python, interface, uml, visio, dia

I'm searching for documentation on how to do it properly. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you google "dia python", you'll find https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Python which is a good starting point